# TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series' for pd.get_dummies

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, typeerror, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to use `pd.get_dummies` on some of the nominal data in a dataframe I have (House Regression from Kaggle). I separated all of the nominal categories into a list of column names, `'obj_nominal'`.

When I call

```
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=obj_nominal)
```

I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'.
```

The only preprocessing I have done so far is remove null values in the dataset. I have also tried using Sklearn `OneHotEncoder`, and it creates the same error.

I have also tried making a separate dataframe using:

```
x = df.iloc[:, obj_nominal]
```

and passing get_dummies on the dataframe:

```
pd.get_dummies(data = x)
```

but still no luck...

The data is downloadable at https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data

Comment: Could you add an example dataframe (just a couple of lines)? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Maybe try: `obj_nominal = df.columns[[pd.api.types.is_string_dtype(df[column]) for column in df.columns]]` It looks like one of your colums was a series of series.

Comment: @Shaido, great link, but my dataframe has 79 features. What would you advise for this? Even just a couple of rows would look a bit... clanky. Also, I am not sure which column is even causing the problem. In the meantime, I will post the link for the competition which contains the dataset.

Comment: @shuaf98: You can remove columns until you have found which one/ones are causing the issue. I guess not all columns are relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the following solved the problem:

By first changing the datatype of every column to string, I remove the issue.

```
x = df.loc[:, obj_nominal]
x = x.astype(str)
```

However, I am not sure entirely what this accomplished, because these were my datatypes of the relevant columns, before I converted to strings:

```
df.loc[:, obj_nominal].dtypes

Street           object
Alley            object
LotConfig        object
LandContour      object
Neighborhood     object
Condition1       object
Condition2       object
BldgType         object
HouseStyle       object
RoofStyle        object
RoofMatl         object
Exterior1st      object
Exterior2nd      object
GarageType       object
MasVnrType       object
Foundation       object
Heating          object
CentralAir       object
Electrical       object
SaleType         object
SaleCondition    object
```